Angular-archwizard compatibilty with Angular 16 and higher version
I have recently upgraded to the Angular 16 and find out that archwizard is no more support the Angular 16 or higher version and there isn't any update from official team also
The legacy ViewEngine has been deprecated and removed in Angular 16.

Please add support for Ivy compiler, as your library now breaks with Angular 16 and its blocking us from updating to the newest Angular version

'ArchwizardModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002) archwizard.module.d.ts(3, 61): This likely means that the library (angular-archwizard) which declares ArchwizardModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Versions:
Angular: 16.0.0
angular-archwizard: 7.0.0

Anyone have solution for this issue or done the upgrade or any other alternate of archwizars which is more similar to this
I have tried to fork referenced library but it doesn't work with Angular 17,
here is reference ArchWizard

Forking an unmaintained lib is probably your best alternative if you really can't drop it.

@MatthieuRiegler do you think angular router could be the alternative for this,

You would have to recreate the workflow, but yeah

@MatthieuRiegler are you using archwizard or you have used in past?

no, it's a fairly small lib. I wouldn't recommend using those, it's too big a risk on the long run as you experienced.
